# Validar celdas vacías de un DataGridView c#

Tags: c#

Estoy validando que no existan celdas vacías en el `DataGridVieW` antes de registrar.El código me funciona bien, pero me gustaría trabajarlo con un `bool`( true false ). de esa manera cuando pase la validación me permita registrar los datos. Intente hacerlo con el `bool` pero me sale siempre celdas vacías.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvListas.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dgvListas.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        if (dgvListas.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null)
        {                 
            dgvListas.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
        }
        else
        {                      
            dgvListas.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para buscar celdas vacias sólo hace falta modificar un poco tu código:

```
private bool ValidateGrid(DataGridVieW dgvListas)
{
bool IsEmptyCell = false;
for (int i = 0; i < dgvListas.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dgvListas.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
         if (dgvListas.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null)
         {
              IsEmptyCell = true;
         }
     }
}
return IsEmptyCell;
}
```

Algunos cambios que se podrían hacer para mejorar:

- Para mirar si un `Value` esta vacio, puedes usar la funcion `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` en vez de mirar sólo si es `null`
- Puedes salir del bucle una vez que hayas encontrado la primera celda vacia y te ahorras seguir buscando.

Con los cambio te quedaría así:

```
private bool ValidateGrid(DataGridVieW dgvListas)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgvListas.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dgvListas.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvListas.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo optimizaría un poco mas el código a algo así: 
`

```
       foreach(DataRow row in dgvListas.Tables(0).Rows)
       {
           if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.ItemArray(0).ToString()))
           {
             /*ACA VA EL CODIGO QUE NECESITAS HACER EN CASO QUE SE DE ESTA CONDICION*/
           }
       }
```